# FFMPEG output duration using "-t" is too long by 10 ms

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using this command to take video from a 35 second QuickTime file and replace audio with a WAV:

`ffmpeg -i 'video.mov' -i 'audio.wav' -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -t 35.0000 'output.mov'`

But the audio is slightly longer than the video, and I'm trying to make  ffmpeg trim the output to **exactly** 35 seconds with `-t 35` but the output is **35.01** seconds.

I also tried `-t 35.000` and `-to 35` and several other options, but it's alway 10ms too long.

`ffmpeg` output:

```
ffmpeg version N-91789-g11cec34829 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-appkit --enable-avfoundation --enable-coreimage --enable-audiotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 19.100 / 56. 19.100
  libavcodec     58. 27.101 / 58. 27.101
  libavformat    58. 17.106 / 58. 17.106
  libavdevice    58.  4.101 / 58.  4.101
  libavfilter     7. 26.100 /  7. 26.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2018-10-09T13:41:49.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:35.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 172467 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 170692 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-10-09T13:41:49.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 (HQ)
      timecode        : 00:01:12:22
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-10-09T13:41:49.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:01:12:22
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-10-09T13:41:49.000000Z
      handler_name    : Time Code Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:01:12:22
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, wav, from 'audio.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoded_by      : Pro Tools
    originator_reference: aaygKpJ1bvMk
    date            : 2018-10-02
    creation_time   : 12:29:34
    time_reference  : 172800000
  Duration: 00:00:35.04, bitrate: 2316 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s
Output #0, mov, to 'output.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf58.17.106
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 170692 kb/s, 0.04 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-10-09T13:41:49.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 (HQ)
      timecode        : 00:01:12:22
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  875 fps=479 q=-1.0 Lsize=  739138kB time=00:00:34.99 bitrate=173024.6kbits/s speed=19.2x    
video:729276kB audio:9846kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.002153%
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution: put the `-t 35` before the `-i audio.wav`:

`ffmpeg -i 'video.mov' -t 35 -i 'audio.wav' -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 'output.mov'`

Comment: That will only limit the data read from the audio, but not the other input. It works for you since your other input has duration exactly 35.0 s, but this isn't a generic solution for others with the same problem.

Comment: I updated the question to be more specific and to match the solution @Gyan

Comment: I experienced a similar, although kind of opposite issue; I used `-t` as an input parameter (the same for all input files) and video was about 70ms too long (happened only in libx265 and 30fps - 30fps/libx264 and 24fps/* worked fine...). Adding a `-t` as an extra output parameter solved the issue for me. However, the audio was still about 20ms longer than specified with `-t`, but I never really needed to fix that...